# Rails Cache Clearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have this in my production environment:

```
# The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true
```

How do I completely clear the cache so changes I deploy take effect? I have added content to one of the pages but it doesnt seem to show up since I set the config.cache_classes to equal true.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use passenger you need to create the file `tmp/restart.txt` or update its modification time if it's already there:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```